# MailMerge в 1 документ VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, macro

В общем не могу разобраться как сделать сохранение файлов в 1 документ.
Имеется код где каждый объединенный файлик сохраняется отдельно.

```
Option Explicit
Const pathtoopen = "C:\Users\kloak\Desktop\Для тестов VBA\Template.docx"
Const FOLDER_SAVED As String = "C:\Users\kloak\Desktop\Для тестов VBA\Test folder\"
Const SOURCE_FILE_PATH As String = "C:\Users\kloak\Desktop\Для тестов VBA\Отчет 12.xlsm"

Sub TestRun()
Dim MainDoc As Document, TargetDoc As Document
Dim recordNumber As Long, totalRecord As Long
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Set wdApp = New Word.Application
Dim pathtoopen As String
wdApp.Visible = True
Set MainDoc = Documents.Open(pathtoopen)
MainDoc.Activate
With MainDoc.MailMerge
        '// if you want to specify your data, insert a WHERE clause in the SQL statement
        .OpenDataSource Name:=SOURCE_FILE_PATH, sqlstatement:="SELECT * FROM [Îò÷åò îáùèé$]"
        totalRecord = .DataSource.RecordCount
       For recordNumber = 2 To 10

            With .DataSource
                .ActiveRecord = recordNumber
                .FirstRecord = recordNumber
                .LastRecord = recordNumber
            End With
            .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
            .Execute False

            Set TargetDoc = ActiveDocument
            TargetDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:=FOLDER_SAVED & .DataSource.DataFields(2) & ".docx"
            TargetDoc.Close False
            Set TargetDoc = Nothing
      Next recordNumber

End With

Set MainDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Ну вместо `TargetDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:=..` просто `TargetDoc.Save`, имхо. Соответственно `Set TargetDoc` вынести перед циклом, а `close/set nothing` - после.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался просто записав макрос а потом просмотрев текст, оказывается если просто отправить в документ указав какие граница в Datasource то и создается целиковый документ, соответственно никаких циклов for не требуется. Пример ниже.

```
With MainDoc.MailMerge
.OpenDataSource Name:=SOURCE_FILE_PATH, sqlstatement:="SELECT * FROM [Отчет общий$]"
.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
            .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
        End With
.Execute
End With
```